# Linux distributions comparison

Tags: linux, comparison, linux-distributions

Does any good comparison exist (like a table of present features) between the many Linux distributions?

What are the features and advantages on each distribution? ([Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29), [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS), etc.)

What choice is better for what kind of user profile?

Comment: Here in the future, Raspbian is pretty popular.  You guys didn't even have Raspberry Pis back in the 0's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wikipedia has a good [comparison table of Linux distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions).  Also, DistroWatch has an [overview of the top ten distributions](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=major).

Comment: That top ten overview on DistroWatch is awesome, good call.

Comment: +1 for Distrowatch. I'd consider the wikipedia comparision page pretty much useless in helping to decide among distros.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic one: http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/30781/0/page/2

This one might also help you out: http://polishlinux.org/choose/comparison/

Answer (score 1):

Not *quite* what you asked for, but this is a really hand test to help you pick:

http://www.zegeniestudios.net/ldc/

Answer (score -2):

My 3 choices for Linux (I don't understand why the others Linux' exist):

- [SliTaz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SliTaz_GNU/Linux): for an old PC/laptop or any live CD/DVD/USB as it can remaked and shared easily.
- [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29): the most used Linux by everyone and they are right.
- [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux): if you want a professional setup don't seek anywhere else.